# React не получается найти данные в объекте

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

Есть код который передает массив в другой компонент, далее мне просто нужно найти в нем свойство thumb.

Сам объект.

[image: Сам объект]

Если попытаться найти свойство thumb в urls вылетает ошибка, что такого не существует.

[image: Ошибка]

Код который я писал, в передаваемых данных лежит то что на первом скрине.

[image: Код который я писал]

Как исправить данную ошибку?

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю, что вы попадаете в функцию `ImageList` несколько раз и, к примеру, при первом входе в функцию там данных пока нет. Попробуйте переписать код следующим образом:

```
function ImageList(props) {
  const { data } = props;
  if (data && data.urls) {
    console.log(data.urls.thumb)
  }

  return (<div></div>)
}
```

Уверен, проблема кроется именно в этом, потому что в `data` у вас лежит пустой объект сначала. Также. проверьте место, откуда вызывается функция `ImageList` и перед ее вызовом добавьте логирование, на всякий случай.

Comment: Спасибо это помогло мне вывести ссылку, но при render'e оно все равно осталось прежним, как я могу сделать логирование?

Comment: @ДаниилСтрельников на самом деле ваш вопрос не совсем ясен, в силу отсутсвия *ключевого* кода. Логирование можете все тем же `console.log` делать. Думаю, что в рендере нужно бы добавить проверку, если там есть значения, которые приходят не сразу.

Comment: Спасибо, вы мне очень помогли)